# Unused Variable OSX

Tags: ios, variables

I am very new to programming, currently trying to progress through the Ray Wenderlich beginner tutorials, but I have fallen at the first hurdle! It appears, either I have set up my program wrong, or the tutorial is out of date as when I began the program we had different code, and when I try to run the code he has produced it came up with errors.

His code

```
// //  main.m //  Are You A WIZARD? //
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>   int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

     NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

     //These are the different variables that will be evaluated to generate responses. 
     float strength, intelligence, speed, alchemy_skill, sum, avg;

     //I included (1-10) so that users would know how to answer.
     NSLog(@"What is your strength (1-10)?");
     NSLog(@"What is your intelligence (1-10)?");
     NSLog(@"What is your speed (1-10)?");
     NSLog(@"What is your alchemy skill level (1-10)?");

     [pool drain];
     return 0; }
```

My code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {

        //These are the different variables that will be evaluated to generate responses:
        float strength, intelligence, speed, alchemy_skill, sum, avg;

        //I included (1-10) so that users would know how to answer.
        NSLog(@"What is your strength (1-10)?");
        NSLog(@"What is your intelligence (1-10)?");
        NSLog(@"What is your speed (1-10)?");
        NSLog(@"What is your alchemy skill level (1-10)?");

    }
    return 0; }
```

When I run his code it has flat out errors such as "NSAutoreleasePool is not available in automatic reference counting mode", and when I run mine it says that I have "Unused variables".

Thanks for any help! I am sure I have made a silly mistake straight away, but some clarification would be most appreciated!

Comment: I wouldn't start to learn programming with Objective C.

Comment: What would you reccomend starting with if I have aspirations to learn ios development in the future?

Comment: @Tom: Start with a simpler scripting language like Python or Ruby. Let them teach you about the OO principles and ideas like message passing. Then you can try objective C. Even better, learn Python/Ruby, than C, and then Obj C, because Obj C is really a combination of Rubyish things and C.

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to accomplish. I think starting out with Python is great and then changing to a language like PHP would be beneficial. Start with Python because you'll learn the fundamentals of programming and PHP because you'll be forced to think very critically and really get to know the language. PHP does not compile, as a direct result, it forces you to think very critically. I think these would be beneficial to any programmer, and the are very useful in the real world!

Comment: The messages are correct -- `-autorelease` is not available when you're compiling with ARC, and you *do* have unused variables. What is your question?

Comment: Okay, so the general consensus is that obj-c is bad beginner language, and python would be much better? After a quick google, I've found a site called "learn python the hard way", and it looks quite good, would this be reccomended as a good learning resource? Are there any other alternatives/better ones?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @MardinYadegar: Learning PHP because it "forces you to think very critically" is like telling people to catch thrown butcher knives blade first because "the stakes are high".

Comment: @Jesper I'm sorry, I can't make the connection. I have felt in my past that when programming in PHP, solving problems were more complex than other languages.

Comment: Starting to learn programming with Python/PHP/whatever-high-level-language is a double-edged sword: it's very easy to have programs working without really understanding what's going on. If @Tom's intention is to program for iOS I'd stay away from these for now, and would go all onboard Objective-C. Probably it's a good idea to learn good old C before trying to learn Objective-C (just to understand which parts come from C, and which parts are Objective-C additions). Although it's possible to learn both at the same time if you are diligent and do some reading of quality materials.

Comment: @MardinYadegar: Yes, exactly. PHP gives you slightly odd tools to solve the problem with, and while that and its lack of useful error reporting helps to raise the level of difficulty, learning how to code will be difficult enough without other barriers. Learning to cope with poor code and bad tools will be covered organically no matter which route Tom goes; no need to crank it up just to make it challenging!

Comment: @Jesper I also recommended PHP for other reasons. I am not the most knowledgeable when it comes to app development, but I believe many data driven apps use PHP.

Comment: @Tom "What language should I learn?" isn't a question that's well suited to StackOverflow (you'll just get a million opinions). That said, [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/learn) seems like a good place to start in any of several languages.

Comment: Don't be discouraged @Tom. Stick with ObjectiveC if you are really interested in it.

Comment: @MardinYadegar: Many data driven apps indeed use PHP and many programmers get work done with PHP. That doesn't mean you have to recommend PHP. PHP lacks strong structure and is chock full of weird inconsistencies and edge cases. Call it snobism if you'd like, but that sort of structure makes accomplishing things in PHP hard and learning other languages even harder. If you're starting from scratch, I don't see an upside to choosing PHP over other choices like Python or Ruby.

Comment: @Jesper: Isn't Python severely inefficient? I have heard that runtimes on Python are significantly longer than many other languages. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62333/python-vs-php-python-runs-slower might be able to solve the answer to this question, but from what I am reading, PHP is slightly faster.

Comment: @MardinYadegar: We've long since passed "on topic" and I'd like to close this discussion, and I don't even use Python, but it's apparently fast enough to be one of Google's choice languages.

Answer (score 2):

You get the `unused variables` warning because of this line:

```
float strength, intelligence, speed, alchemy_skill, sum, avg;
```

You declare 6 variables here and never do anything about them. The compiler warns you about this because normally it's a problem, but if you're going to use them later, it's OK.

As for his code, it is outdated, and was made before the creation of something called ARC, which is a complex solution to an even more complex probelm.

I agree with @Mardin in the comments. Don't start programming with Obj C. I started after five or six other languages, and parts of it still give me headaches. It's a better second or third language.

Comment: Right, okay! I assumed it was something to do with the tutorial being a little outdated, and I guess its pretty obvious now that unused variable means that the variables are unused.. Feeling pretty dumb! Ah well, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Tom: Sure! Just keep on going. Objective C can be elegant and easy, but only when you know more about programming in general.

Answer (score 0):

You're right on both counts.

`NSAutoreleasePool is not available in automatic reference counting mode`

This is because you are running your code in a different mode then he is running his. Automatic reference counting (circa 2012) does the memory management automatically while before you had to manually keep track. Two possible recommendations:

- Don't use ARC. Then his code will work out of the box.

You can do this by starting a new project and unchecking "use automatic reference counting" during the configuration stages.

- Remove the autorelease code:

  ```
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

  int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

      //These are the different variables that will be evaluated to generate responses:
      float strength, intelligence, speed, alchemy_skill, sum, avg;

      //I included (1-10) so that users would know how to answer.
      NSLog(@"What is your strength (1-10)?");
      NSLog(@"What is your intelligence (1-10)?");
      NSLog(@"What is your speed (1-10)?");
      NSLog(@"What is your alchemy skill level (1-10)?");
      return 0;
  }
  ```

I would recommend picking a more up-to-date tutorial or continue on with a no-arc project.

To your second question on unused variables, XCode is telling you that you have variables that you make but don't use. As you can see, you create `strength` et al and don't use them. It's not a problem. I'm assuming that you'll need to use them later on in the following steps.